# The position of the items in my SwipeMenuListView is random after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, random, position

The position of the items in SwipeMenuListView changes randomly after scrolling. The items in the listview are also not visible like only items upto Item 5 is displayed in the Listview.
Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Item> initArrayList() {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new Item("Item 1", "First Item on the list", "abc", "Item 1.4", "Item 1.5"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 2", "Second Item on the list", "xyz", "item 2.4", "item 2.5"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 3", "Third Item on the list", "qwe", "item 3.4", "item 3.5"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 4", "Forth Item on the list", "qwe", "item 4.4", "item 4.5"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 5", "Fifth Item on the list", "qwe", "item 5.4", "item 5.5"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 6", "Sixth Item on the list", "qwe", "item 6.4", "item 6.5"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 7", "Seventh Item on the list", "qwe", "item 7.4", "item 7.5"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 8", "Eight Item on the list", "qwe", "item 8.4", "item 8.5"));
    return items;
}
```

Here is my DataAdapter and Item class:

```
public class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList;

public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList) {

    super(context, R.layout.list_item2, itemsArrayList);

    this.context = context;
    this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // 1. Create inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 2. Get rowView from inflater
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, parent, false);

    // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    TextView tv4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    TextView tv5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv5);

    // 4. Set the text for textView
    tv1.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTv1());
    tv2.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTv2());
    tv3.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTv3());
    tv4.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTv4());
    tv5.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTv5());

    // 5. retrn rowView
    return rowView;
}
```

Here is mu Item class:

```
public class Item {

private String tv1;
private String tv2;
private String tv3;
private String tv4;
private String tv5;

public Item(String tv1, String tv2, String tv3,String tv4, String tv5) {
    super();
    this.tv1 = tv1;
    this.tv2 = tv2;
    this.tv3 = tv3;
    this.tv4 = tv4;
    this.tv5 = tv5;
}

public String getTv1(){
    return tv1;
}

public String getTv2(){
    return tv2;
}

public String getTv3(){
    return tv3;
}

public String getTv4(){
    return tv4;
}

public String getTv5(){
    return tv5;
}
```

Comment: You have to use setTag and getTag inside getView - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600599/how-to-use-settag-and-gettag-with-custom-adapter