# How to get position of item and delete it using Cursor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making **webview** app that contains a **bookmarks** i successfully added items into **listView** using **Cursor** and **SQLite database** but my problem is i can't get **position** of item and delete it i tried to do it in my own way but what i got is i had deleted all content of list view. this is my **MainActivity**, i made a **longClickItemListener** to delete listview item on long click and this is my **BookmarkDatabase**

**Main Activity**

```
final Dialog bookmarksScreen = new Dialog(this);

        bookmarksScreen.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        bookmarksScreen.setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmark);

        bookmarksScreen.setCancelable(true);

        final ListView listView = bookmarksScreen.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_list);
        ImageView bookmarkBack   = bookmarksScreen.findViewById(R.id.close_bookmarks);
        ImageView bookmarkDelete = bookmarksScreen.findViewById(R.id.delete_table);

        // populate an ArrayList<String> from the database and then view it
        final ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = bookmarkDB.getListContents();
        // check if there is no data on database
        if(data.getCount() == 0){
            Log.d("Database Bookmark", "There is no items on item list");
        } else {
            while(data.moveToNext()) {
                // add data into table "COL1" and "COL2"
                theList.add(data.getString(1));
                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_listitem, theList);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                webView.loadUrl(item);

                bookmarksScreen.dismiss();

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final int which_item = position;

                // here i want to delete listview item

                return true;
            }
        });

        bookmarkBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bookmarksScreen.dismiss();
            }
        });

        bookmarkDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showConfirmDialog();

                bookmarksScreen.dismiss();

            }
        });

        bookmarksScreen.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        bookmarksScreen.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        bookmarksScreen.show();
```

**Bookmarks Database**

```
package com.rixhion.mint.databases;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BookmarksDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bookmarks.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bookmarks_data";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "ITEM1";

    public BookmarksDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " ITEM1 TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item1);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getListContents(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor deleteSpecificContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Here i want to get the position of item and delete it
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would be using the primary key somewhere retrievable in your views (Or, vice versa, use as a primary key, a value that is already used somewhere retrievable). Since your Primary Key here is an `auto_increment` field, there is no real reliable correlation between it and the view you are trying to delete (At least from what I can see on your code). One approach would be to use a custom `Adapter` for your list, rather than an `ArrayAdapter`, and using the `View.setTag()` and `View.getTag()` methods to store the primary key on each of your List's items. You can see how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23601341/4844299), as well as several online custom Adapter tutorials.

Assuming your `activity_listitem` layout has a `TextView` with id `text_view`, where you display the text fetched from your database, and to which you have added the Tag storing the primary key, you can do the following in your Main Activity:

```
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            final Integer which_item = (Integer) textView.getTag();    //Assuming you stored the ID as an Integer
            int rowsDeleted = bookmarksDB.deleteSpecificContent(which_item);
            if(rowsDeleted == 0){  //should be 1, since we're deleting by Primary Key
                //if you would like like, handle if nothing was deleted
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And in your BookmarksDatabase class:

```
    public int deleteSpecificContents(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL1 + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    }
```

---

Another approach, if you do not want to use a custom `Adapter`, would be determining the item you want to delete by using its position on the list. You can do this by querying the Database, and iterating on the `Cursor` until it matches the position of your item on the List.

```
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor data = bookmarkDB.getListContents();
            int i = 0;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                if(i == position){
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            int rowsDeleted = bookmarkDB.deleteSpecificContent(data.getInt(0));
            //again, handle if rowsDeleted != 1 if you want
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Your `BookmarkDatabase.deleteSpecificContent()` method is exactly the same as in the first approach for this one - the only difference is in how you determine the id of the item to be deleted. If you would not like to handle the case where `deleteSpecificContent()` does not return 1 (unless I'm missing something major here, it *should* always return 1 in your use case), feel free to change its signature to `void`, rather than `int`.

Note that this second approach is more expensive than the first one, since it requires an additional Database query, and could iterate on the `Cursor` a lot. While it requires a lot less new/changed code, it may not be advisable to use (I honestly cannot say for certain. It is *probably* fine for your use case, depending on the size of your Database, but - full disclosure - I am not experienced enough with Android to make this call. Use at your own discretion).

Comment: The only way for me to fix that is using custom list view, its more easy for me as i added more textviews and image to get favicon of website so, your both solutions are the best and i chosen the first one cause its easier and efficient. thanks you for saving my day :)